# how to record multiple sounds in musical application android

Tags: java, android, audio, recording

I am developing a musical piano app for android, in this app i want to record sound which user play by clicking piano buttons. I am using soundpool to play piano sounds. now for recording android gave us two api's MediaRecorder and AudioRecorder. but for both we have to set MediaRecorder.AudioSource. i didn't want to record sounds from mic because user sound can be included and more important sound quality decrease in recording. then i try to read bytes of that resource file which is played on clicking piano app. and when user click again and again then bytes will be together in global byte array. but when i play global byte array then this play only one resource file and one time only. 
More important thing is i am new to android development. kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although i did not find answer of my question, but now i am using technique for recording aspects which i want to share with all of you. Above function which i try to use is totally wrong option when you are trying to save music created by your app at run time. now for my first version i just saving the clicks of piano buttons along with system time in an array. now when i play that clicks it will play same sound as user try to record. i save these notes in database for further reuse by users.although this is not solution because these notes will be played in our app only, but this is good feature which we can add in our app. when i solve the correct solution, i will share with you guys

Comment: Your solution seems to me like storing the note ids (or frequencies). In such a way like a tracker (Amiga ProTracker, or PC FastTracker or ModPlugTracker) or a MIDI recorder would do. Maybe a MIDI sequence recorder would be an option, since MIDI is a standard and the files can be also played by software synthesizers.

Comment: If i am not wrong mogplug tracker is creating the sounds and we can record these sound notes and export this sound as *.raw or *.wav or *.flac.    Yes Actually i also want the same concept sound produce by user clicks is saved in file and i can export this file as *.mp3 or *.wav which can be used by default media player of android devices. but i dont know where from i start

Comment: Yes, it stores the sounds as part of the file (the names into the header and the byte contents into the footer, if I remember well). To store a file (mp3 or image or whatever) into a text file is easy: as the mht file format (which was my inspiration) does: store it as a Base64 encoded string) - I used this technique in VB.NET to store cover arts + album infos altogether. So, it works.

Comment: problem i am facing is that how to record multiple sounds playing simultaneously or how mogplug works to store notes. i am stuck on that point  ........   however i try to save the bytes of sound files in one file when that sound play. but that technique not works because all bytes were saved in main recording files.

Comment: For very SMALL sounds, the best choice is using the **SoundPool** object, which can play UP TO **32 sounds** simultaneously, if I remember well.

Comment: yes i am playing sounds with soundpool ,and also their is an option to play background music which i am playing with mediaplayer,now problem is that if background music is playing and sound pool also play sound how do  i record both sound.

Comment: So you want to mix the sounds and record them... Maybe this link helps? http://mobilengineering.blogspot.it/2012/06/audio-mix-and-record-in-android.html

Comment: i have read the link which you give me.thanks for that link ,i explore many things from link,but still their is problem,we have to continuously writing data in file and their also an option let suppose sound clip is 10s long but user play 2 second,now inputstream read all bytes from file which is against the recording and let suppose if we get time and get data from that sound file as according to time,does this not slow our app or any delay in recording.and this delay distract our user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55496/discussion-between-yasiriqbal776-and-der-golem).

Comment: no that link also didn't work
conclusivly that app helps to play sounds together and this work i already have done but problem is how to record :(

Comment: Will this help? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Comment: by recording through mediarecorder sound quality is very bad and also sound from mic is also included in recording while audiorecorder is low level api and it record file by reading buffer, and we have to put bytes in buffer where from audio recorder is reading record.i have tried both method after then i post my question ,

Comment: now i think i have to study synthesizers and their working and then implement it in android